# WINDOWS 2012R2 Server - edit arp cache default timeout values

Tags: windows, timeout, arp, arptables

I'm trying to edit / change the default duration of the ARP cache entries stored in a Windows 2012R2 server TCP/IP stack (for IPv4 entries).

I've tried to edit the following OS registry keys:
-"ArpCacheLife" 
-"ArpCacheMinReferencedLife" 
located under
HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters

as described in 
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc957524.aspx#mainSection
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc957525.aspx

but apparently there's no change in the default ARP cache entries timeout behavior.

Also, no changes are apparently introduced to both ARP caches that windows 2012R2 uses:
- ARP referenced entries
- ARP unreferenced entries

I would be grateful for any suggestion and reference to the corresponding technical documentation.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

See [Description of Address Resolution Protocol (ARP) caching behavior in Windows Vista](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/949589/description-of-address-resolution-protocol-arp-caching-behavior-in-win). Although it says Vista other versions are listed.  I used the query instructions and they worked.